# Rich man transforms into a T-Rex to save Earth from aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel

Looking for a book for a friend so some of this may be a bit vague as I didn't read it myself. This was a sci-fi/fantasy book supposedly read in 1989 so published anytime that year or before. The plot involves a young (teen or 20s) male protagonist who is a self made billionaire as he has some kind of magic or latent ability that has allowed him to manipulate the stock market. At the start of the book he's making stock deals while hang gliding around his private island.

The overarching plot is that aliens have been mentally linked to humanity (possibly forever) as they are waiting for the perfect vessel to I think take control of to save their race. They don't realise this link works 2 ways and all this time humanity have been influenced by these aliens. From them we got understanding of magic and science, and took their words like witches or gravity to explain things, however we spell it wrong (so in the book the alien may spell it as "wytches" for example).

The aliens send a female witch from a planet to Earth, to lure the protagonist to said planet. She has a familiar (a cat I believe) who is actually a demon. However they fall in love instead. The aliens apparently require despair to fully take control of him so they transport the woman back to the planet. Instead of despair however, the protagonist just gets angry and with his anger comes heightened powers. He somehow gets to the planet that is full of dinosaurs and in his search for his lover he realises that he gains more powers the angrier he gets. He eventually is able to transform into a half T-Rex/half-man and at some point is also flying a pterodactyl (that may or may not shoot lasers??).
He eventually saves Earth from the aliens because he can't be controlled.

The cover of the book was pastel pink and blue and have the protagonist standing in the middle but with T-Rex legs and surrounded by fairies. The title was apparently one word, but possibly a made up word from the story. It was something to do with transformation or metamorphosis.

If you could help me identify this book I'd be so grateful because my friend has been searching for it for 33 years!!

Comment: Could it be a comic series? Possibly [Devil Dinosaur](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_Dinosaur)?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be this one unfortunately :(